# Python summing itertools.count?

Tags: python, count, python-itertools, infinite

I'm having some trouble with the itertools.count function, and I don't quite understand what it does.  I expect the code below to accomplish [Project Euler problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/problem=2).

I know that I could write this with a simple while loop, but is there a way to do it with a list comprehension?  This code just freezes as I guess it's going to go infinity with count().  I would have hoped it would stop after x > MAX, but I know that won't happen.  Is there a way to stop count in a generator expression like below?

```
def fib(n):
    if (n <= 1): return 1
    else: return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


MAX = 4000000

infiniteFib = (fib(x) for x in count())

s = (x for x in infiniteFib if x < MAX and x % 2 == 0)

print sum(s)
```

Comment: Either way, this is a *terribly* inefficient function for calculating Fibonacci values. Anything past mid-30s takes forever to return on my machine, and it's a pretty beefy one.

Comment: I have the actual function memoized, so it's not _as_ bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just need to tell the `infiniteFib` generator when to stop yielding elements. [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) provides a number of useful methods to help with this:

```
less_than_max = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<MAX, infiniteFib))
even = itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x%2==0, less_than_max)
print sum(even)
```

We get a generator for all the numbers yielded by `infiniteFib`, until one returned is greater than `MAX`. Then we filter that generator, choosing only the even numbers. And finally we can sum the result.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import count, takewhile, imap
>>> sum(x for x in takewhile(lambda x: x < 4000000, imap(fib, count())) if x % 2 == 0)
4613732
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
def fib():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield b
        a, b = b, a+b

sum(f for f in itertools.takewhile(functools.partial(operator.ge, 4000000), fib()) if f % 2 == 0)
```

Or, pushing the parity check into the generator:

```
def even_fib():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        if b % 2 == 0: yield b
        a, b = b, a+b

sum(itertools.takewhile(functools.partial(operator.ge, 4000000), even_fib()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `count()` just keeps going, which isn't what you want. List comprehensions / iterator expressions don't have flexible exit conditions (but see @DSM's solution using `takewhile`).

I prefer just using `while`.

Here's my old answer to Euler 2:

```
def SumEvenFibonacci(limit):
        x = y = 1
        sum = 0
        while (sum <= limit):
                sum += (x + y)
                x, y = x + 2 * y, 2 * x + 3 * y
        return sum

ce = SumEvenFibonacci(4000000)
print ce
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using `takewhile`, but non-recursively. Since the recursive solution requires calculating all the `fib`s less than n for each n, it's horrible slow.

```
def fib_gen(only_even=False):
    one = 1
    if not only_even:
        yield one
    two = 1
    if not only_even:
        yield two
    while True:
        next = one + two
        one = two
        two = next
        if only_even:
            if next % 2 == 0:
                yield next
        else:
            yield next

list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 4000000, fib_gen()))
```